# Control M cyclic jobs with same schedule should not run in parallel

Tags: job-scheduling, control-m

I have a control M cyclic job A which runs every 40 mins from 8.30 am to 3 pm.
I have to create a new cyclic job B which has to run from 9 am to 4 pm.
Job B should not run in parallel with job A. If job A fails, job B should still run and vice versa.

What are the options I should give while creating job B.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a condition between jobs or just drag and drop arrow. This way cyclic job B will only run when job A is completed

Answer (score 0):

Add a control resource or quantitative resource which will prevent both jobs from executing at the same time.